# Is there an efficient algorithm for finding a minimal common subset of pairwise distinct bits in a set of bit strings?

Tags: substrings, comparison, string-metrics

I am working on an efficient mapping function represented as a directed graph. In essence, it is a sort of radix trie. A path must be formed from a bit string [string hereon] efficiently. To do this, I decided on looking for and using an algorithm that finds a continuous, common subset of bits at a particular offset and length from a set of strings. I will describe the general algorithm that I seek formally as follows:

Given:
$$S := \left\{s_y | s_y = B_y \right\}$$
$$B_y := \left\{b_x | b_x\in \left\{0,1\right\}\right\}$$
and $$s_{y,x} = B_y[x]$$
we seek to find a common subset
$s_{1...|S|,p...q}$ such that $\forall\left\{p, q \right\}\in\Bbb{N}$,
$\nexists \left\{p', q' \right\}\in\Bbb{N} \text{ s.t. } |p' - q'| < |p - q|$.

For the general case, the common subsets permit to find $s_{1...|S|, p_k...q_k}$. Some analysis shows that
$\lceil\log_2(|S|)\rceil \leq |p - q| \leq \lfloor\log_2(s_{largest}
\lor 1)\rfloor + 1$ where $s_{largest}$ is the string whose magnitude $|B_y|$ is greater than all other $|B_y|$ in $S$.

As an example algorithm for demonstration, suppose we have the following four strings, each four elements in length:
$$
s_1 = \left\{1, 0, 1, 1\right\}\\
s_2 = \left\{0, 1, 0, 1\right\}\\
s_3 = \left\{1, 1, 0, 1\right\}\\
s_4 = \left\{1, 1, 1, 1\right\}
$$

We define a column thusly:
$$c_{x} = s_{1...|S|,x}|x\in\Bbb{N}$$
with $c_1$ being the first column, ***right to left order*** convention, and $c_{|S|}$ being the last.

0. $p_c\leftarrow 1$. $q_c\leftarrow 0$. Column offset and (horizontal) width variables, respectively.
1. We see that the column $c_1$ is all ones, so we decide to skip it and go to $c_2$. Increment $p_c$ and $q_c$.
2. $c_2$ varies, but there are only two distinct values of the four in $c_{1..2}$ read by rows. Increment $q_c$.
3. The column $c_3$ varies, and we see that there are three distinct values when read by rows, not four, so we move on to the next column. Increment $q_c$.
4. $c_4$ varies. Increment $q_c$.
5. We observe that all the columns we have, $c_{1...q_c}$, are now pairwise distinct when read by rows. Record $p_c$ and $q_c$. Terminate algorithm.

(Proof: the values read by rows interpreted as binary integers and converted to base ten read as $[5, 2, 6, 7]$.)

It's quite obvious that there is a deterministic algorithm hidden somewhere in this process using some combination of Hamming weight and XOR: for any given column, the Hamming weight of the XOR of any two columns $c_a$ and $c_b$ tells us how many unique values are represented by the common subsequence given by offset $p$ and length $q$, but I haven't yet figured out how to generalize this just to create a deterministic algorithm for all columns.

If this algorithm already exists, I do not know what it is called. For my particular implementation it would be ideal if the whole set did not have to be analyzed each time a key is added to our map, but that previous information from previous computations can be used to quickly analyze a new key and determine whether or not we need to extend the sequence again, or can keep the existing index and sequence length.

What already exists that can be implemented? If not already existing, are there any ideas on how best to proceed with an optimal algorithm as described here?

Comment: Note: the naive algorithm that checks if each value is correct without redundant comparisons in $\frac{1}{2} k(k + 1) = O(n^2) \cdot O(n) = O(n^3)$ time (this formula comes from the partial sum formula for $\sum_{k=0} k$; the other $n$ from the number of times in which we would have to apply the uniqueness check as per bit) obviously isn't desirable, even for the static case. You can get $O(n^2)$ time by building and traversing a binary tree, but this isn't desirable either. An $O(n)$ time algorithm (recursive or explicit) would be ideal.

Comment: I am having a hard time parsing what is meant by "determine what common sequence of distinct bits in a group of unique strings is sufficient to differentiate between them".  Can you specify the algorithm mathematically, perhaps by listing the inputs and the desired output?  An example is not a substitute for a clear problem specification.

Comment: What is meant by continuous?  Do you mean contiguous?  Do you mean given strings $a_1,\dots,a_n$ you want to find $i,j$ such that $a_1[i..j],\dots,a_n[i..j]$ are pairwise distinct, where $a[i..j]$ represents the substring of bits at indices $i,i+1,\dots,j$ in $a$?  Why can't we set $i=1$ and $j=n$, i.e., use the whole string?  Are you trying to minimize $j-i$ or something?  I don't understand what your remark about XOR and Hamming weight is referring to or where that enters in.  Are you assuming there are $n$ strings and each string is $n$ bits long?

Comment: @D.W. Apologies. I'm not well-versed in formal terminology unfortunately as I learn by informal methods. Edits are most welcome. Yes, that is what I mean by continuous. Yes, we do want to minimize $j-i$ as we only want as much information as is necessary to differentiate between all $a_n$ which are known beforehand to be pairwise distinct strings whose lengths in bits are arbitrary. I'll do my best to reformulate the question mathematically as I have gained some experience with that.

Comment: @D.W. By meditation, I've figured out that reading by columns and taking the Hamming weight, we can detect if there are any bits that vary. If they're all the same, then we can either skip that column, or just add it to the list and increment the index. The Hamming weight of the XOR of adjacent bits along the columns gives me information about how many unique values are represented between two adjacent columns as XOR in principle is $1$ for different, and $0$ for same.

Comment: Now, that's well and good, but the question I haven't answered is how many distinct values can the bits represented by the current index and offset $i + k$ in the set $a_n$ represent, and how many more bits do I need given the current $(i, k)$.

Comment: What's $n$?  The number of strings?  The length of each string?  Can I construct an algorithm that is usually efficient for average/"typical" strings, or does it need to work for worst-case strings?

Comment: @D.W. Did you get a chance to reread my post? I rewrote it to describe it formally. Everything should be explained now.

Comment: @AMDG, can't believe I was explaining binary to you just 9 years ago. So glad to see you stuck with it and you're now talking over my head.

Comment: @alvonellos ecks dee yeah and it's kind of a problem too because I can't really explain anything well the first time around in case the fact that this 2yo question died the moment I decided to clarify what I meant didn't make that obvious enough, and I'm stuck in this odd place terminologically between high school freshman and university PhD because I never attended the latter.

Comment: @AMDG when you truly grasp something hard, you can make it very very simple. Focus on heightening your understanding of the subject and you'll be able to explain it to a five year old. It's crazy how that works.

Comment: @alvonellos That... that's not how understanding works. Q _can_ imply P here, but P _does not_ imply Q. I don't know how that goes over so many heads. One can lack language and understand. That's the case with me. The simple fact of the matter is that 1. I don't know what friendship is, nor how other people think. 2. English is the absolute worst language in the world. It's full of ambiguities, and that's why I find myself (needlessly?) explaining what I mean all the time because of all the inkhorn words and ambiguities thanks to French, Latin, and Greek morphology invading English morphology.